# What is worng with my code?

Tags: debugging, batch-file, if-statement, set, echo

```
@echo off
color c
set 1=direwolf15
set 2=direwolf16
set 3=magicworld1
set 4=magicworld2
set 5=magicfarm
set 6=magicfarm2
set 7=ftblite1
set 8=ftblite2
set 9=horizons
set 10=monster
set 11=unleashed
set 12=techworld1
set 13=techworld2
echo "--------------------------------"
echo "|   Universal server starter   |"
echo "--------------------------------"
echo.
echo ==================================
echo 1. Direwolf 1.5
echo 2. Direwolf 1.6
echo 3. Magic Word l
echo 4. Magic Word 2
echo 5. Magic Farm 1
echo 6. Magic Farm 2
echo 7. FTB Lite 1
echo 8. FTB Lite 2
echo 9. Horizons
echo 10. Monster
echo 11. Unleashed
echo 12. Tech World 1
echo 13. Tech World 2
echo ===================================
echo.
set /p "whattostart=Enter the number of the server to start: "%=%
if "%whattostart%" == "1" (start /min \direwolf1.5\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \direwolf1.5\ (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "2" (start /min \direwolf1.6\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \direwolf1.6 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "3" (start /min \magicworld1\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \magicworld1 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "4" (start /min \magicworld2\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \magicworld2 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "5" (start /min \magicfarm1\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \magicfarm1 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "6" (start /min \magicfarm2\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \magicfarm2 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "7" (start /min \ftblite1\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \ftblite1 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "8" (start /min \ftblite2\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \ftblite2 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "9" (start /min \horizons\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \horizons (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "10" (start /min \monster\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \monster (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "11" (start /min \unleashed\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \unleashed (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "12" (start /min \techworld1\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \techworld1 (echo that server does not exist)
if "%whattostart%" == "13" (start /min \techworld2\startserver.bat ^& exit)
IF NOT EXIST \techworld2 (echo that server does not exist)
pause
exit
```

every time i try to run it it says the server does not exist even if i have the folder and the batch file in it. i have no idea how to fix it, I am a beginner in batch programing so some help would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: And now with fixed code it doesn't find the file
Here is a picture of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCY3F.png

Comment: whattostart should be put in inside percent sights te get its value: %whattostart%

Answer (score 0):

To access the value inside a variable , you need to use

```
if %whattostart%=="1" ....
```

but, if you look at the above line, the comparision is between a quoted string (`"1"`) and the value of the variable, that will not be quoted (unless the user type the quotes, of course). So, the line should be

```
if "%whattostart%"=="1" ....
```

And, just to minimize problems with the user input, your `set /p` line should be

```
set /p "whattostart=Enter the number of the server to start: "
```

Comment: Thanks and i have 1 more problem, and that is that it does not find the specified file but its there inside the a folder

Comment: @user3297060, from the screen capture the path is `\batch\direwolf1.5\startserver.bat`. If a path starts with a backslash , it is handled as an absolute path from the root of the volume. Relative paths does no start with a backslash. If the startserver.bat files are in a folder under the location of the menu.bat file , either omit the initial backslash or use `.\direwolf1.5\startserver.bat`